# Track performance issue

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, ftp

I made a piece of code which takes a file, analyze it (XML Parser), create some data in the database (JPA/Hibernate/Postgres) and do some FTP transfers (apache commons-net). This piece of code works well :)

My workmate is responible forf testing. He tells me that when he tests it on thousands of files (for migration purposes), the piece of code is fast at the beginning but progressively slows down.

I added some code to track the time that my piece of code takes for each file. Here is the result for ~4500 files :

[image]

As I can see, it takes 250ms/file at the beginning then takes up to 1 min for each file. The program uses 100% CPU but have no memory problem (I have 16Go RAM)

There is one hibernate transaction per file (so no transaction accumulation).

Do you know if there is a common bug which can progressively slow down the program or do you know a way to easily drill down?

Comment: Do you properly close the streams when you finish reading the file?

Comment: Hmmm, found one, thanks:) I fix it and retry.

Comment: if that does not solve it, download yourkit and profile your app.  that will tell you where the time is going and it will also be able to confirm your assertion concerning memory usage (having 16GB does not mean that there is not a high level of GC churn or leaks eating up old gen)